# Number of permutations 6 digits three numbers

Tags: permutations

I've lost my PIN that encrypts the hard drive of my laptop ! What I can recall narrows the permutations down to a number that would be worth a brute force attempt I think. It got me thinking, how does one calculate the permutations given the following:

- It's a 6-digit PIN (length of 6)
- I only used the numbers 1, 2 & 3
- each one appears at least once
- no digit appears 4 times or more
- no sequence of 3 of the same digit?

Comment: It says each appears at least once, not only once. Meaning I used 1, 2 & 3 at least once. 112211 is not valid for instance because it does not contain 3

Comment: Please also share your efforts on solving this problem

Comment: `how does one calculate the permutations given the following` if you're only interested in generating such sequences (not solving math problem using pen and paper), it's easy to make a program which generates all 3^6 sequences and drops out "bad" ones. To solve this on paper you probably have to exploit the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: I'd happily do that if I could access my laptop! I'm no mathematician so I will have to look that up but yes essentially I want to try all combinations if the number isn't too large. I really just wanted to get a feel for what the number was.

Comment: Several hundreds. 300-500, I guess.